# Android add crescent shape border to one side of view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, progress-bar

I have a plain old `recyclerView` next to a `relativeLayout` inside a `verticalLayout`. Nothing fancy about it at all. I am adding some `progressBars` instead the `recyclerView` and I was wondering if there's a way to have a cresent shape cut out of the left side of it. Kind of like those typical RPG portraits where the bars are curvered around the picture - only this would scroll around it.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: An illustration would be helpful. Also by verticalLayout, do you mean a LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes. Here is a quick example: http://bashooka.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/game-ui-kits-34.jpg On the top right of the image you see that the "resource" bars are rounded to fit the image (circle). Mine is just about the same although I would like it to be able to scroll up and down with multiple bars and the bars will basically form around it. I know it has something to do with drawing but I am not sure where to start. I see it done in iOS all the time (hoping there's some equivalent).

Comment: You could create a [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) and use it as a background for your view.

Comment: I'll look into it - I couldn't find any examples of people doing this yet you see so many RPG game UIs on Android. No idea how they made them